# Reset Messages window size and position to factory default in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, messages, big-sur, plist, defaults

How do I reset Messages's window size and position to its factory default in macOS Big Sur? I have tried deleting a couple of `.plist` files (i.e. `com.apple.iChat`, `com.apple.imessage`, `com.apple.Messages`, etc.), but nothing's worked...

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't just drag it back to how you want it?

Comment: I want to learn how to manipulate things like this for learning purposes.

Comment: Good luck with that ;)) See [What file is responsible for saving window position?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/393988/what-file-is-responsible-for-saving-window-position)

Answer (score 1):

The right identifier for Messages is `com.apple.MobileSMS`. Big shoutout to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/140299). Try deleting the associated `.plist` for that, which worked for me.